# How to remove the div refer to id name in jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove all div class contain '.dashboard-row' with number excluded row 0, can I use regex to remove?

Here's the simple HTML for you to refer. In this case, I would like to remove the class

dashboard-row dashboard-row1

dashboard-row dashboard-row2

dashboard-row dashboard-row3

dashboard-row dashboard-row4

```
   <div class="dashboard-row dashboard-row1">
      ....
   </div>
   <div class="dashboard-row dashboard-row2">
      ....
   </div>
    <div class="dashboard-row dashboard-row3">
       ....
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-row dashboard-row4">
       ....
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-row dashboard-row0" style="visibility:hidden">
        ....
    </div>
```

Currently, I just hard code tp remove the div like this. But I think it is not the good solution.

```
for(var i=1; i<=1000;i++)
{
    $('.dashboard-row' + i).remove();
}
```

Comment: You should paste part of HTML here as you are speaking of `all div id contain '.dashboard-row'` but your JS code is selecting class attribute. I guess you can just do $('.dashboard-row'.remove() no need for loop

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div[class^="dashboard-row"]').remove();
```

The selector matches every `div` with a `class` that starts with `dashboard-row`.

---

Since you have not posted your HTML, I do not know if `dashboard-row` is the *first* class listed in the attribute. You can use this instead:

```
$('div[class*="dashboard-row"]').remove();
```

This selector matches every `div` with a `class` that includes `dashboard-row` **anywhere** inside it.

---

Now that you have posted you HTML...

```
$('div.dashboard-row').remove();
```

is all you need.

Comment: Sorry, I want to make some change..... If I would like to remove excluded the id dashboard-row0, how to do it?

Comment: @ChrisMok: THis is how you do it, `$('div[id*="dashboard-row"]').remove();`

Comment: Sorry I have provide some HTML in question.